# prove that $\operatorname{null}(A) = 0$ iff has linearly independent columns

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this question.

How would you prove $\operatorname{null}(A) = 0$ if and only if  $A$ has linearly independent columns.

thanks.

Comment: It should be $\text{null} (A) = \{ 0 \}$. Given a vector $x$ with appropriate dimensions, can you see how $Ax$ is a linear combination of columns?

Answer (score 3):

It's important to realize that $Ax$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$.

In other words, if the columns of $A$ are the column vectors $a_1,\ldots,a_n$, and $x \in \mathbb R^n$, then
\begin{equation}
Ax = x_1 a_1 + \cdots + x_n a_n.
\end{equation}

With this viewpoint, we see immediately that $Ax = 0$ has a nontrivial solution if and only if the columns of $A$ are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 1):

This is a special case of the [Rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) which says that the number of linearly independent columns (rank) and the dimension of the null space (nullity) add up to the total number of columns.

In this case nullity is zero and rank is the number of all of the columns.